# PT100 - 39250 Cubic fit formula

Tags: temperature, calibration, rtd

I'm currently using a cubic fit formula I found online to derive the temperature of a PT100/385 RTD using resistance. The formula is **-247.29 + 2.3992*R + 0.00063962 *R^2 + 0.0000010241 *R^3** where R is Ohms. Does anyone know where I could find a similar formula for a 39250 RTD? I've tried to find one online, but I have had no luck.

I need to use this instead of the standard Linear one because I need more accurate readings at high temperatures.

Comment: Where's the link to the datasheet? Does it give you three or more R-T values? You also need to specify whether the formula gives you °C or °F. There's an edit link under your question. Welcome to EE.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the old-fashioned so-called "American standard" RTD, they're seldom used these days. You can find [Callendar-Van Dusen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callendar%E2%80%93Van_Dusen_equation) equation coefficients for those, and some other types, on [this](http://www.ni.com/documentation/en/ni-daqmx/latest/measfunds/rtdtypes/) National Instruments web page.

[image]

If your RTD is 50 ohms, just scale it (double the measured resistance) so it fits the 100 ohm equation.

Comment: Thank you! Would you happen to know the variation of the Callendar-Van Dusen equation which solves for temperature with an input resistance?

Comment: Ah, I would use a search to invert it but you could fit it to a polynomial for least squares error. I don’t think the results would be as good with the latter.